# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model,

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Trying to `save one-to-one relationship` between `Expense` and `ExpenseCategory` and got error like above

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, null given, called in /home/z3r0/Desktop/Kiyoi/laravel-kiyoi/app/Http/Controllers/V1/ExpenseController.php on line 88

i tried `google` and everything, but still no luck.

**In Expense Model**

```
    public function expense_category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\ExpenseCategory::class);
    }
```

**In ExpenseCategory Model**

```
    protected $fillable = ['expense_id', 'code', 'name', 'description'];

    public function expense()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Expense::class, 'expense_id');
    }
```

**In ExpenseController**

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'date' => 'required',
            'amount' => 'required',
        ]);

        $expense = Expense::findOrFail($id);
        $expense->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $expense->date = $request->date;
        $expense->description = $request->description;
        $expense->amount = $request->amount;
        $expense->expense_for = $request->expense_for;
        $expense->save();

        $expense_category = \App\ExpenseCategory::findOrFail($id);
        $expense_category->name = $request->name;
        $expense->expense_category()->save($request->expense_category);

        return response()->json([
            'updated' => true,
        ]);
    }
```

I'll appreciate of all ur help.. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. You're passing `$request->expense_category` into the `save()` method, but you meant to pass in `$expense_category`.

Change

```
$expense->expense_category()->save($request->expense_category);
```

to

```
$expense->expense_category()->save($expense_category);
```

Comment: i got this error `No query results for model [App\ExpenseCategory] 10`

Comment: @z3r0 `$expense_category = \App\ExpenseCategory::findOrFail($id);`: you don't have an expense_categories record with that id.